# How to test code where large files are needed

Tags: c#, linq

I have some video files which i need every time i run my app. It checks if `HD` free space is less than one gigabyte, if true keep deleting the oldest date file and so on until there is enough space available.

```
        foreach (DriveInfo drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
        {
            if (drive.IsReady && drive.Name == "E:\\")
            {
                if (drive.TotalFreeSpace < 10000000)
                {
                    do
                    {
                        DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(@"E:\REC\Video\");
                        FileInfo[] files = info.GetFiles().OrderBy(p => p.LastWriteTime).ToArray();
                        System.IO.File.Delete(@"E:\REC\Video\" + files[0].Name);
                    }
                    while (drive.TotalFreeSpace < 10000000);
                }
            }
        }
```

The vidofiles are autogenerated (recorderded) over months. 
So: **How can I test this code without having to wait until my discspace is full?**

Comment: _does my code will work as i imagine?_ Why don't you try it?

Comment: because i have a 230gb free space

Comment: @MagedEWilliam: then re-write your code to be testable.  We're not your test suite.

Comment: Try testing it on a virtual machine?

Comment: Instead of 1 gb try the code with 230 gb free space and check the condition i.e. instead of 1 GB you 230 GB in condition.

Comment: SO is about fixing code issues, not doing code review.

Comment: And the code review will not be very positive...

Comment: @MagedEWilliam, try checking for Hd free space == 320 gb (or better yet Hd free space <= 320 gb) and test it that way. If it works then, it should work for 1gb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put the code in its own method. Put the needed discspace in a parameter:

```
public class HdCleaner
{

    public static void DeleteOldestFiles(long minimumAvailableSpace, string path)
    {
        var driveLetter = Path.GetPathRoot(path);
        var drive1 = DriveInfo.GetDrives().Where(d => d.IsReady).Single(d => d.Name == driveLetter);

        while (drive1.TotalFreeSpace <= minimumAvailableSpace)
        {
            var info = new DirectoryInfo(path);
            var file = info.GetFiles().OrderBy(p => p.LastWriteTime).First();
            file.Delete();
        }
    }
}
```

For testing do a unit test:
Make sure there are some Files in the path that can be deletet.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void DeleteOldestFilesTest()
    {
        const string driveLetter = "C:\\";
        const string path = "C:\\Users\\user\\FileCleanerTest";
        var drive = DriveInfo.GetDrives().Where(d => d.IsReady).Single(d => d.Name == driveLetter);
        var availableSpace = drive.TotalFreeSpace;
        var neededSpace = availableSpace + 10000;

        HdCleaner.DeleteOldestFiles(neededSpace,  path);

        var newAvailableSpace = drive.TotalFreeSpace;

        Assert.IsTrue(newAvailableSpace >= neededSpace);
    }
```

P.S.: I did some refactorings ;)

Answer (score 0):

i tested it, and i replace the 10000000 so i did right click on the drive and copy the current free space add some bytes and it worked, and i had to change it a bit, to be like this:

```
            foreach (DriveInfo drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
        {
            if (drive.IsReady && drive.Name == "E:\\")
            {
                if (drive.TotalFreeSpace <= 245000000000000)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        while (drive.TotalFreeSpace <= 245000000000000)
                        {
                            DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(@"E:\REC\Video\");
                            FileInfo[] files = info.GetFiles().OrderBy(p => p.LastWriteTime).ToArray();
                            System.IO.File.Delete(@"E:\REC\Video\" + files[0].Name);
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```